# UTF-8 conversion?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, utf-8

I'm grabbing a JSON feed but weird characters shows up in the JSON feed. For example pass\u00e9 represents passé. i already utf-8 it with `NSUTF8StringEncoding`

i'm using the next JSON:

```
NSString *jsonString = [NSString 
                        stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UrlXml] 
                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                        error:nil];


    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *results = [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil];

    parser = nil;
```

Comment: Where does the display problem crop up - in the console or on the screen?

Comment: On the screen, in my tableview

Comment: If `jsonString` is OK, that's SBJSON's bug. Otherwise, the choice of the encoding is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data you're receiving from the JSON feed has the literal text `pass\u00e9` in it (as 10 ASCII bytes with a literal 'backslash' character in it) then the data is not UTF-8 encoded. You should use `NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding` instead. That encoding will convert `\u####` sequences to the proper Unicode characters.

Comment: @Jones: It's important to check whether the JSON data contains the text `pass\u00e9` or `pass\\u00e9`. If it's the latter, then the result you got is correct and you should not attempt to change your decoding code; it's the source data that's incorrect, so it's the source data that you should fix (or get its owners to fix).